# How to make comments reply work in my website?

Tags: comments

I am trying to make the threaded/nested comments work in my theme, but wiht no success. Tried code snippets, custom js codes and other alternatives, but cant make it work. Already enqueued the scripts in child theme's functions.php. Tried do enable/disable comments options im my theme preferences, but nothing has changed. Switched to Twenty-Twenty and worked fine(also in localhost). Dont know what else to do. Am kind of new in wordpress development. This is the testing website:

https://homolog.canalsolar.com.br

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you edit your question to include the code you're using for custom comments? If comment replies aren't working out of the box on your theme you would need to contact their support routes to report the issue as 3rd party theme support/dev questions are offtopic here and you can't ask for help with something you bought

Comment: it looks like you're using the https://themeforest.net/item/salient-responsive-multipurpose-theme/4363266 theme with a child theme named `salient-child`, do comments work if you disable the child theme and use just Salient? If it works with Salient but not Salient Child then you need to include the changes you made to the child theme that broke comments. If Salient on its own has no replies then you must go to their support routes